# for x in file.split('\r\n'): TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.7

I want to basically search for key-words in a list, but I am unsure how to fix my code so I don't get this error.

```
suspicious = []

zip = zipfile.ZipFile("C:/Users/Oliver/Documents/website_urls/urls.zip")
file =  zip.read("domain-names.txt")
for x in file.split('\r\n'):

    if "apple" in x and "support" in x:
        print("suspicious address found"+ x)
        suspicious.append(x.replace('\n', ''))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are mixing str with bytes.
The value of file is bytes so you can not split it by a string('\r\n'). You have 2 choices here:

1. Convert the split character to byte (b'\r\n'). In this case you also have to change your if in condition to use bytes and also replace the characters you have in replace to the byte since x also is bytes
2. convert file to string (file.decode("utf-8") if your file is utf-8) in this case your code should work fine without any more change

So the simple change would be this(second approach)

```
suspicious = []
zip = zipfile.ZipFile("C:/Users/Oliver/Documents/website_urls/urls.zip")
file =  zip.read("domain-names.txt")
for x in file.decode("utf-8").split('\r\n'):

    if "apple" in x and "support" in x:
        print("suspicious address found"+ x)
        suspicious.append(x.replace('\n', ''))
```

Byte base approach(first approach)

```
suspicious = []
zip = zipfile.ZipFile("C:/Users/Oliver/Documents/website_urls/urls.zip")
file =  zip.read("domain-names.txt")
for x in file.split(b'\r\n'):

    if b"apple" in x and b"support" in x:
        print("suspicious address found"+ x)
        suspicious.append(x.replace(b'\n', b''))
```

Answer (score 0):

The read function on a Zipfile returns bytes.

So decoding the bytes in utf-8 format, which is the safest encoder you can use for a text file if you do not know the exact encoding

```
suspicious = []

zip = zipfile.ZipFile("C:/Users/Oliver/Documents/website_urls/urls.zip")
file =  zip.read("domain-names.txt").decode('utf-8')
for x in file.split('\r\n'):

    if "apple" in x and "support" in x:
        print("suspicious address found"+ x)
        suspicious.append(x.replace('\n', ''))
```

Comment: This fixes one problem, but creates a new one.

Comment: Thank you, i tried that and then got an error telling me it wanted a string not bytes LOL, however I fixed the issue. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you change it like that it will work:

```
suspicious = []

zip = zipfile.ZipFile("C:/Users/Oliver/Documents/website_urls/urls.zip")
file =  zip.read("domain-names.txt")
for x in file.split(b'\r\n'):
    strX = str(x)
    if "apple" in strX and "support" in strX:
        print("suspicious address found"+ strX)
        suspicious.append(strX.replace('\n', ''))
```

Answer (score 0):

`zip.read` returns a `bytes` object. If you know it is text, you should decode it first to a `str` object before working with it further.

```
zip = zip.read("domain-names.txt").decode()
```

You might also want to make use of `io.StringIO`, so that you can treat the contents like a file.

```
import io
import zipfile

zip = zipfile.ZipFile("C:/Users/Oliver/Documents/website_urls/urls.zip")
file = io.StringIO(zip.read("domain-names.txt").decode(), newline=None)
for x in file:
    if "apple" in x and "support" in x:
        print("suspicious address found"+ x)
        suspicious.append(x.rstrip('\n'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to .decode() file object before "for" loop. Corect code below.

```
suspicious = []

zip = zipfile.ZipFile("C:/Users/Kamil/urls.zip")
file =  zip.read("domain-names.txt")
file = file.decode()
for x in file.split('\r\n'):

    if "apple" in x and "support" in x:
        print("suspicious address found"+ x)
        suspicious.append(x.replace('\n', ''))
```